# Is there a way to display two different answers to a Yes/No question?

Tags: c#, loops, console

It's the first time I'm using Stackoverflow. I'm new to programming and English is a secondary language, so be patient for any mistakes or misunderstanding.

I'm trying to code a Yes/No question with three different outputs regarding what's typed by the user. I'll try to explain.

I'm displaying a question to which the user has to answer "Y" or "N". If he clicks on any other Key, it will display: "You've made a mistake, try again" and he's asked to click again on "Y" or "N".

If he clicks on " Y ", I want to display a message saying something like "Alright, let's go!" and if he clicks on " N ", I want to display a message saying something like " That's sad " and here, the application console closes.

I tried and looked for different tutorial but none of them seems to respond exactly to what I want.

Here's the code I have for now :

```
void YesNo()

       bool confirmedY = false;
       bool confirmedN = false;

       do
       {
           ConsoleKey response;
           ConsoleKey response2;  

           do
           {
             response = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

             if(response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                 Console.WriteLine("You've made a mistake !\n Please try again [Y/N]");

            } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);

            confirmedY = response == ConsoleKey.Y; 
            response2 = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            confirmedN = response2 == ConsoleKey.N;

            if(confirmedY)
                Console.WriteLine("Too bad for you !");

            if(confirmedN)
                Console.WriteLine("That's a good choice! Let's go");

        } while (!confirmedY && !confirmedN);

        Console.WriteLine("That's a good choice! Let's go");
```

I hope that's clear! Thanks for your help

Comment: what exactly is not working as you intend to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have so many of logical problems.

```
            do
            {
                response = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                if (response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    Console.WriteLine("You've made a mistake !\n Please try again [Y/N]");

            } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);
```

The first response is not Enter, that means event you give all keys (included Y/N) and except Enter would show "You've made a mistake"

Another problem is you are using 2 times key reading, it doesn't make sense at all

```
            confirmedY = response == ConsoleKey.Y;
            response2 = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            confirmedN = response2 == ConsoleKey.N;
```

And the other: 2 times not neccessary loop, reuse code,...

My refactor

```
    static bool IsValidKey(ConsoleKey key)
    {
        return key == ConsoleKey.Y || key == ConsoleKey.N;
    }

    static void YesNo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click [Y/N]");

        do
        {
            var response = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            if (!IsValidKey(response))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You've made a mistake !\n Please try again [Y/N]");
                continue;
            }


            if (response == ConsoleKey.Y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That's a good choice! Let's go");
                break;
            }

            if (response == ConsoleKey.N)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too bad for you !");
                break;
            }

        } while (true);
    }
```